# Integration by parts and dv being an unknown function

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have an integral of the form
$$\int_t^sxf(x) \, dx$$
that I want to compute using IBP.  Let $u = x$ and $dv = f(x)$.  What does the evaluation of the first part look like?  Is it

$$x\Big\vert_t^s\int_t^sf(x)$$

or

$$\left[x\int f(x)\right]_t^s$$
or something different?

Comment: Second one is correct.

Comment: Taking $dv=xdx$ seems like a more natural choice though.

Comment: @kingW3 You are probably right, but this is for a particular proof I am studying.

Comment: @DemetriP Note that the correct assignment is $dv = f(x) dx$, the differential is missing in your post. You cannot equal a differential to a finite function.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx=\Bigg[f(x)\int g(x)\: dx\Bigg]_a^b-\int_a^b\Big[f'(x)\int g(x)\: dx\Big] dx$$

if you choose $f(x)$ as the first function.

Answer (score 0):

In

$$\int_a^b f'(x)\,dx=\left.f(x)\right|_a^b=f(b)-f(a)$$ the vertical bar notation applies to the antiderivative as a whole.

This holds when doing by-parts integration

$$\int_a^b f'(x)g(x)\,dx=\left.(f(x)g(x))\right|_a^b-\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)\,dx,$$

which can also be written

$$\int_a^b f'(x)g(x)\,dx+\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)\,dx=\int_a^b(f(x)g(x))'\,dx=\left.(f(x)g(x))\right|_a^b.$$

Answer (score 0):

Integrating $\int_a^b x\>f(x)\>dx$ by parts in the desired way means considering $f$ as derivative of some other function $F$. One then has
$$\int_a^b x\>f(x)\>dx=\int_a^b x\>F'(x)\>dx=\biggl[x\>F(x)\biggr]_a^b-\int_a^b F(x)\>dx\ .$$
Which primitive  $F$ of $f$ one chooses plays no rôle, but one has to insert the same primitive $F$ at both places where $F$ appears on the right hand side.